# Ways to arrange groups of books

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I've got a simple probability question similar to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2894376/ways-to-arrange-books).

It is as follows:

> Given a collection of books, of which 25 are blue, 10 are green and 5 are black, in how many ways can someone arrange 10 books if they want a green on on each end and alternate blue and black ones for the rest. Books of the same color are distinguishable from each other.

I believe the answer is $n = 10*25*5*24*4*23*3*22*2*9$, alternating blue and then black. But I was unsure if it was instead $2n$, because it could be ordered with black and then blue. Is my thinking correct?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your count should be doubled because the second book could be blue or black.  You have required that the second book be blue.  The order of factors will be different if the second book is black, but the factors will be the same and the product will be the same.